# Laravel 4 - Deleting a record from the database

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Once again, i am stumped.

I have a table of letters, each with the following link attached

```
<a href="">Delete {{ $letter->lettername }}</a>
```

From the docs i can see i have to run the following from my routes.php

```
$letter = Letter::find(1);
$letter->delete();
```

My question is, what do i have to enter in the href to pass the letters ID onto the routes file, and then how do i pass that to the find() parameter?

Do i do something like this

```
<a href="letters/delete/IDHERE">Delete {{ $letter->lettername }}</a>
```

If so, how do i put that ID into the find paramter.

Im confused.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Cheers

My Routes file is as follows:

```
Route::get('letters', array(
'before' => 'auth|userdetail',
function()
{

    // Grab the letters, if any, for this user
    $letters = Letters::forUser(Auth::user())->get();

    $data = [
        'letters' => $letters
    ];

    return View::make('letters', $data);

}
));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
<a href="letters/delete/{{ $letter->id }}">Delete {{ $letter->lettername }}</a>
```

[But it would be better if you have a named route](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes)

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('letters.delete', $letter->id) }}">Delete {{ $letter->lettername }}</a>
```

Then in your routes

```
Route::get('letters/delete/{id}', array('as' => 'letters.delete', 'before' => 'auth|userdetail', function($id)
{
    echo ("You want to delete letter id: " . $id . " from the system");
    // Put your delete code here
}
```

Comment: Does that mean i would need a seperate controller for the letters? instead of using the routes file?

Comment: No - post your routes file in your question.

Comment: Ok, i have added all i have got to the question

Comment: Ok, thats interesting ... So in the delete code $id would automatically be the ID?

Comment: Thats pretty easy ... Thank you for your help